# Почему не работает стандартная передача id элемента?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Почему в vue3 нельзя передать свой id как это обычно делается в js?

```html
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        data() {
          }
    },
    methods:{
      show: function(id){
      console.log(id)
    }
</script>
<template>
  <button id="hi" @click="show(this.id)">Привет</button>
</template>
```

p.s. на просторах интернета нашёл один рабочий способ, но он выглядит коряво и странно

```html
<script>
        export default {
            name: 'App',
            data() {
              }
        },
        methods:{
          show: function(event){
          console.log(event.currentTarget.id)
        }
    </script>
    <template>
      <button id="hi" @click="show($event)">Привет</button>
    </template>
```

Comment: потому что шаблон обрабатывается `vue` а не остается как есть ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: И после обработки this указывает не на button, а на компонент vue, у которого никакого id не видать.